# How to setup terminal service gateway in my RDP client

Tags: rdp, windows-terminal-services

I am using "RD Tabs" to bypass the terminal service gateway to RDP to the remote host. Usually I use browser and go to https://webvpn.company.com:777 with my account.

Now in RD Tabs advanced settings, it's asking server name and authentication method. How should I fill this information?

I tried below:

```
server: webvpn.company.com:777
authentication: Attempt TLS
```

But it's not working, what could be wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the Remote Desktop Client without RD Tabs, does authenticating with the TS Gateway using that same information work?  I would focus on that first.

Comment: Yes. That's how I log on.